# Internet Explorer Repeatedly Queries Empty DNS Record: Causes Page to Hang

Tags: dns, internet-explorer

When I visit http://www.okcfox.com a DNS query is made when loading the website to `widgets.fox.com`.
The DNS server I am pointing to does not have a record for `widgets.fox.com`.

When I try to load the page in IE, it repeatedly tries to acquire the DNS record at the expense of freezing IE until a timeout has passed (thirty seconds or so).
I understand that I could just point to a new DNS server, but what I'm actually trying to figure out is why Firefox understands that our DNS server doesn't have a record and moves on with loading the rest of the page, but IE does not do this.

I've googled for quite a while and have come up with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In the command prompt, type "ipconfig /flushdns" with out the quotes.  This should flush the bad entry and cause your browser/windows to request new entries.

Comment: The entry on the DNS server does not exist.  It isn't a problem with the local cache.  What I'm trying to figure out is why IE queries the DNS server over and over again and firefox does not.